# Cutting collection field short in Meteor to make an ingress

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor, underscore.js

In my Meteor project's home page where I am showing the latest post, I would like to show only the first 140 characters of the post and then a `Read more`-button.

Say I have

```
Posts = new Meteor.Collection('posts');
```

And `Posts`has a `.body`-field which is where I store the main text. Then in the template helpers file I guess is where I have to do surgery:

```
Template.home.helpers({
    var posts = Posts.find();
    //surgery on all body fields in posts
    posts: posts
});
```

I figure I have to perhaps use UnderscoreJS' `_.each()` and the jQuery's `.substring()`, 
but how I am going to do it and put it all together is where the problem is.

Comment: The `prune` function in [underscore-string](https://github.com/epeli/underscore.string) is helpful for this. There is an atmosphere package for it [here](http://beta.atmospherejs.com/package/underscore-string-latest).

Comment: @DavidWeldon Great! That made it more beautiful by adding three dot's when the text was longer that 140 characters, but left them out for shorter ones. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could solve this entirely with CSS3 and (pure) JavaScript.

CSS3 introduces a new attribute `text-overflow`, as described here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow

You could use that in conjunction with a limited width/height of a `div` or `span` and then follow that with your "read more" link. The link would need to do nothing more than change the width/height (perhaps with an animation if you want).

Alternatively, if you really want to use meteor for that, then you could add a `transform` function to your find:

```
var posts = Posts.find({}, {transform: function(post) {
    post.short = post.body.slice(0,140);
    return post;
});
```

And then just use `{{ short }}` in place of `{{ body }}`.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't think about the CSS3 way, that's a good idea. I went for the JS soloution though, as it seems to be what works best for my soulution! Thanks mate!